# Apache Kafka + Kryo Serialization

Tags: java, serialization, kryo, apache-kafka

I am very much new to Kafka and Kryo. I have been working with simple String messages over Kafka with the default Kafka Serializer but I'm trying to use Kryo Serialization wihout success.

Could someone explain or show me an example of sending some java object over Kafka with kryo Serialization (Producer and Consumer)?

I have seen other questions in stackoverflow about the same topic without answer and I cannot comment on it. Apologize in advance.

Thanks.

Comment: what have you trying so far?

Answer (score 4):

I am probably digressing from the question but wanted to provide some of our experience.

We started with Kafka + Kyro and while it is certainly can be done, we found that schema management with Kyro could be troublesome in long term. So we rather went with Jackson serilaizer (org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper).

To implement a Kyro serializer you would just need to inherit Kafka's serializer

```
   import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;
   public class KryoSerializer implements Serializer<YourObject>
```

and override serialize method.

Good luck.

Comment: Don't forget to mention the benefits of using Jackson Smile, which is binary JSON ;)

Comment: Kafka comes with its own JSONSerializer using Jackson, btw